# error de conexion a base de datos php

Tags: php

me sale estas advertencias y no se como solucionarlo

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 6
>
> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 8
>   Failed to select the database

Codigo relacionado

```
<?php
ob_start();
include("costants.php"); 
    $db_connection=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS); 
      if (!$db_connection){ die("if database connection fail" . mysqli_error());} 
       mysqli_query('CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS malawisales');  
    $db_select=mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$db_connection);        
    if(!$db_select){ die("Failed to select the database".mysqli_error());}

                        $stable5="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblbuyers (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                                  Firstname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                  Surname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                  Phone varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                   Device_id int(11)NOT NULL,
                                   Time varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                                   Location text(15)NOT NULL,
                                   Agreement varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                                   Date varchar(15)NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id) )";
                                 mysqli_query($stable5);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El código arroja tres advertencias o *Warnings*:

### Primera advertencia

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 6

Significa que `mysqli_query()` espera dos parámetros, pero le estás pasando solamente uno. Cada vez que uses `mysqli_query` tienes que pasarle como primer parámetro la conexión y como segundo parámetro la consulta SQL que quieres ejecutar. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.query.php), y los ejemplos del estilo procedural, que es el que estás usando. Aunque te recomendaría que uses el estilo orientado a objetos, porque es mucho más claro y fácil de entender y se presta a menos confusión.

### Segunda advertencia

> Warning: mysqli_select_db() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 7

Dice que en el parámetro 1 espera la conexión, pero le estás pasando una cadena. Esto ocurre porque le estás pasando los parámetros al revés. Primero va la conexión y luego el nombre de la base de datos. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.select-db.php), y los ejemplos del estilo procedural. Además, en mysqli esto sólo es necesario si quieres cambiar de base de datos. Para conectar, puedes pasar el nombre de la base de datos en el cuarto parámetro de `mysqli_connect()` y ahorrarte esto.

### Tercera advertencia

> Warning: mysqli_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\APP\Sistema Web de Control de
>   Minimarket\WebControlMinimarket\includes\dbconnection.php on line 8
>   Failed to select the database

Más de lo mismo. Te dice que `mysqli_error()` espera un parámetro (la conexión), pero que no le estás pasando ninguno. [Revisa la documentación](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.error.php) y los ejemplos del estilo procedural.

Ahora vamos a corregir tu código. Y, para futuros errores sobre cualquier función, **revisa la documentación**. PHP está bien documentado y en español, con ejemplos siempre sobre los estilos orientado a objetos y procedural, según el caso.

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include("costants.php"); 
    #Pasamos DB_NAME como 4º parámetro
    $db_connection=mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME); 
    if (!$db_connection){ 
        die("if database connection fail" . mysqli_error($db_connection));
    } 
    mysqli_query($db_connection,'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS malawisales');
    /* 
       *Las dos líneas siguientes sobran las puedes borrar  
       *a no ser que quieras crear la tabla en malawisales (ver ADVERTENCIA)
       $db_select=mysqli_select_db(DB_NAME,$db_connection); Esta línea la puedes borrar        
       if(!$db_select){ die("Failed to select the database".mysqli_error());}
    */
    $stable5="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblbuyers (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                                 Firstname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                 Surname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                 Phone varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                                 Device_id int(11)NOT NULL,
                                 Time varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                                 Location text(15)NOT NULL,
                                 Agreement varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                                 Date varchar(15)NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id) )";
    mysqli_query($db_connection,$stable5);

?>
```

**ADVERTENCIA**: En el código anterior, la tabla se creará en `DB_NAME`. Si quieres que se cree en la base de datos nueva, `malawisales`, podrás cambiar de base de datos antes de ejecutar `$stable5`:

```
$db_select=mysqli_select_db($db_connection,'malawisales'); #OJO, no se usa DB_NAME, sino  malawisales    
if(!$db_select){ 
    die("Failed to select the database".mysqli_error());
}
$stable5="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tblbuyers (id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                             Firstname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                             Surname varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                             Phone varchar(30)NOT NULL,
                             Device_id int(11)NOT NULL,
                             Time varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                             Location text(15)NOT NULL,
                             Agreement varchar(15)NOT NULL,
                             Date varchar(15)NOT NULL,PRIMARY KEY(id) )";
mysqli_query($db_connection,$stable5);
```

Comment: Uy veo que esta pregunta está marcada como duplicada de otra. Tu respuesta aquí es más completa ¿Crees que se podría cambiar el orden de los duplicados?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' no sé si sea posible. Habría quizá que proponerlo/preguntarlo en Meta.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' dando seguimiento a tu comentario, creo que esta pregunta no es realmente duplicada de la otra, porque aquí OP presenta tres situaciones a las que respondo una por una. La primera es la misma que la otra pregunta, pero no las otras dos. Supongo que habrá algún procedimiento para pedir que sea reconsiderado el duplicado.

Comment: Como usuario con la medalla de oro de la etiqueta [tag:php], puedes reabrirla con tu solo voto. De todos modos, yo ya emití el mío porque sí tienes razón que esta pregunta abarca más temas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el error se basa en que no estas enlazando tu conector (`$db_connection`) con tus querys, por ejemplo, cambia el código de cada `mysqli_query()` de la siguiente manera.

Agragando tu "conector" como primer parámentro de la funcion:

```
mysqli_query($db_connection, 'CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS malawisales'); 
//y también
mysqli_query($db_connetion, $stable5);
```